# Vertical align within absolute positioned div with no height?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive website, and the standard "tricks" to get the div content vertically aligned are not working due to the fact that my container is absolute positioned.

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="prod-info">
        <div class="valign">
            <h3>Vantage</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum luctus laoreet lacus, in viverra metus pharetra sit amet.</p>
            <div class="btns">
                <a href="#">View Details</a>
                <a href="#">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ftd-img"><img src="images/products/picture.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

`.prod-info` is absolute positioned inside a floated element `.product`.  I need what's inside `.prod-info` to be vertically aligned, but I can't seem to get it to work... I attached a JS Fiddle with the code and CSS I have so far...Any help would be greatly appreciate.

http://jsfiddle.net/BFQx8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you wanted by using the technique explained in [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) article. Here's the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BFQx8/4/

I added the content inside `.prod-info-container` and added a ghost element to its parent `.prod-info`. Ghost element has 100% height and they both are inline blocks, this way the content is aligned to middle vertically. Added css code is as following:

```
.product-feed .prod-info:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.prod-info-container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I need it to be vertically centered on whatever the height of the `.product` container is, which in this case is the height of the picture.

Comment: What I did exactly does that. I don't see any problem on the fiddle I posted. Doesn't it work?

Comment: The fiddle you posted still shows everything vertically aligned to the top. The content is not centered.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I haven't tested it with Chrome. It's working fine now both on Firefox and Chrome. I've updated the fiddle link.